# EPPlus custom header column names

Tags: c#, epplus

I have following code, which generate me an excel with header row. The column names of header are named as variables in DataItem class.

```
// class for single row item
    public class DataItem
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }

    // Retrive data items from database and store into conllection.
    var rows = database.GetData().ToList();

    // Create table from collection with automatic header
    ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(rows, true, TableStyles.Medium25);
```

excel header output :

```
Number | FirstName | LastName | Country
```

How my output can be customized for example (spaces added etc.):

```
Number | First Name | Last Name | Country
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use **DescriptionAttribute** from **System.ComponentModel** namespace to set column names in the header.

```
public class DataItem
{
    public int Number { get; set; }

    [Description("First name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Description("Last name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to force formatting for EPPlus on a decorator if not... how do I search for a column address based on a header/property name?

Comment: Selected answer though this didn't work out for me

Comment: I think this is the perfect way to do such things. Thanks Patrick.

Answer (score 4):

I have it, solution is following

```
ws.Cells["A1"].Value = "Number";
ws.Cells["B1"].Value = "First Name";
ws.Cells["C1"].Value = "Last Name";
ws.Cells["D1"].Value = "Country";
```

Comment: Just want to add that you need to do call the LoadFromCollection method with  false for the second parameter - PrintHeaders. Start from the second row and don't print the headers from the collection: workSheet.Cells[2, 1].LoadFromCollection(rows, false);

Comment: @Koshera I am not sure if I used the second parameter, because even if the headers will be printed, I think the additional value settings will overwrite the names, but thank you for the mention of that parameter.